# ¿Cómo crear una llave privada con crypto-js en nextjs?

Tags: nextjs, openssl

Estoy tratando de enviar una mensaje encriptado con una llave pública y codificado en base64, este lo envio a traves de query params en la url de mi apliacion de next y recibe correctamente el parametro pero al momento de crear la llave privada que tiene la aplicacion esta arroja el siguiente error:

```
error - Error: error:1E08010C:DECODER routines::unsupported
    at Object.createPrivateKey (node:internal/crypto/keys:620:12)
    at descrypt (webpack-internal:///(api)/./pages/api/helpers/descryp.js:39:18)
    at handler (webpack-internal:///(api)/./pages/api/auth/verify.js:10:69)
    at Object.apiResolver (/home/dell/proyectos/liquidacion_avaluo_app/node_modules/next/dist/server/api-utils/node.js:366:15)
    at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)
    at async DevServer.runApi (/home/dell/proyectos/liquidacion_avaluo_app/node_modules/next/dist/server/next-server.js:481:9)
    at async Object.fn (/home/dell/proyectos/liquidacion_avaluo_app/node_modules/next/dist/server/next-server.js:735:37)
    at async Router.execute (/home/dell/proyectos/liquidacion_avaluo_app/node_modules/next/dist/server/router.js:247:36)
    at async DevServer.run (/home/dell/proyectos/liquidacion_avaluo_app/node_modules/next/dist/server/base-server.js:347:29)
    at async DevServer.run (/home/dell/proyectos/liquidacion_avaluo_app/node_modules/next/dist/server/dev/next-dev-server.js:709:20) {
  library: 'DECODER routines',
  reason: 'unsupported',
  code: 'ERR_OSSL_UNSUPPORTED',
  page: '/api/auth/verify'
```

Este es mi codigo donde debo validar el mensaje encriptado

```
import { createPrivateKey, privateDecrypt, constants} from "crypto";

export default function decrypt(hash){
    let key = `-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----
    -----END RSA PRIVATE KEY-----`;        
    
    const ciphertext = Buffer.from(hash, 'base64');  
    
    key = createPrivateKey(key); // Aquí genera el error
    
    const plaintext = privateDecrypt({
        key,
        padding: constants.RSA_PKCS1_PADDING
    }, ciphertext)
    
    console.log(plaintext.toString('ascii'));

}
```

El codigo anterior es un archivo en una carpeta helpers dentro de pages/api y este es importado desde el controlador que recibe la query param (en este caso hash).

Lo que he intentado para verificar si hay problemas con el codigo es ejecutando el archivo de JS que contiene el codigo anterior pero directamente con node.js, de la siguiente manera `node decrypt.js` y ha funcionado a la perfección, crea la llave privada sin ningun problema y logra desencriptar el mensaje.

Answer (score 0):

Al parecer todo era porque tenia mi llave privada la estaba tomando mal desde la variable que tenia en mi codigo, lo que terminé haciendo es pasar mi archivo .pem que contiene la llave privada a mi proyecto en next y no teniendolo desde una variable

```
import { createPrivateKey, privateDecrypt, constants} from "crypto";
import { readFileSync } from "fs";

export default function descrypt(hash){
    const privateKey = readFileSync("..path_de_mi_llave_privada/private.pem", "utf-8");

    let ciphertext = Buffer.from(hash, 'base64');      
    const key = createPrivateKey(privateKey);
    
    
    const plaintext = privateDecrypt({
        key,
        padding: constants.RSA_PKCS1_PADDING
    }, ciphertext)
    
    console.log(plaintext.toString('ascii'));

}
```